# Optimization on Vector-ODEs for parameter estimation

Tags: julia

So I'm trying to estimate Parameters from given Data, which I generated by solving the ODE problem with given parameters first and then adding a random stray around the result. Using the build_loss_objective I generated the cost function which is  then inserted into optimization. From here, the estimated parameter values can be gathered by result.minimizer .

My first working example for regular ODE looked like that:

```
using DifferentialEquations, Random, Plots
using DiffEqParamEstim, Optim

\###############################################

# ODE Model
```

###############################################

```
function fun(G,p,t)
 k, β  = p
 #ODE
 dG_dt = k - β\*G
 return dG_dt
end

\#Parameter values
p = [0.8, 0.2] #"true" Parameter values
G_ini = 0.0
tspan = (0.0,10.0)
\#ODE Problem
prob = ODEProblem(fun,G_ini,tspan,p)
\#solving ODE Problem
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())

\###############################################

# Synthetic Data

\###############################################

dataset = [(t,sol(t)+0.2randn()) for t in 0:0.01:10]

\#########
\#Cost function and Optimization
\############################

\#Gathering

dataTime = [d[1] for d in dataset] #time points
dataValues = [d[2] for d in dataset] #Data

cost_function = build_loss_objective(prob,Tsit5(),L2Loss(dataTime,dataValues),maxiters=10000,verbose=false)

initialGuess = ones(2) #guesssed parameter values
result = optimize(cost_function, initialGuess, BFGS())

with that example I can get estimated values for the 2 parameters k and β
```

But..........
Now I want to extend the parameter estimation and for that I'd like to estimate parameters on a system of Vector-ODEs. Going from my last simpler exapmle I got something like:

```
using DifferentialEquations,DiffEqParamEstim,RecursiveArrayTools
using Optim,Plots

\###############################################

# ODE Modell

 \###############################################

n=10
function f(du,u,p,t)
 du[1,1] = dc_n = 4*p[1]*u[1,1] -u[1,1]*u[1,2]  
 du[1,2] = dc_d = p[2]*u[1,2]^2 + u[1,1]*u[1,2]

 du[n,1] = dc_n = 3*p[1]*u[n,1] -u[n,1]*u[n,2]                     
 du[n,2] = dc_d = -2*p[2]*u[n,2]^2 + u[n,1]*u[n,2]


 for i in 2:(n-1)
    du[i,1] = dc_n = p[1]*u[i-1,1] -u[i,1]*u[i+1,2]               
    du[i,2] = dc_d = -p[2]*u[i-1,2]^2 + u[i,1]*u[i+1,2]
 end

end

u0 = hcat(ones(n), ones(n))
tspan = (0.0,10.0)
p = [1.5,2.0,1.2]

prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan,p)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())

\###############################################

# Synthetic Data

\###############################################
dataset = [(t,sol(t) .+0.2randn()) for t in 0:0.01:10]

dataTime = [d[1] for d in dataset] #Auffassen Zeitpunkte
dataValues = [d[2] for d in dataset] #Auffassen Exp. Data
\#until here everything works

cost_function =  build_loss_objective(prob,Tsit5(),L2Loss(dataTime,dataValues),maxiters=10000,verbose=false)
initialGuess = ones(3) #alle Parameter auf eins gesetzt (Ratewerte)
result = optimize(cost_function, initialGuess, BFGS())
```

when running the "optimze" function, it tells me in the terminal that there has been a failure and no parameters have been estimated.
Where exactly would I need to change something to make this code work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the way the synthetic data and loss function are constructed. Since your system of ODEs is now a vector, you should ensure that the `L2Loss` objective is aligned with the dimensionality of your data. You can try reshaping the `dataValues` as a vector before using them in `L2Loss`:

```
dataValuesVector = vcat([d[:] for d in dataValues]...)
cost_function = build_loss_objective(prob, Tsit5(), L2Loss(dataTime, dataValuesVector), maxiters=10000, verbose=false)
```

Also, make sure that the number of parameters in your initial guess matches the number of parameters in your ODE system. Your code snippet shows an initial guess of three parameters, but only two are being used in your function `f`. If there are only two parameters, make sure the initial guess reflects that:

```
initialGuess = ones(2) # if there are only two parameters
```

Lastly, verify the logic within your ODE system `f` as the code snippet has some repetition and may not align with your mathematical model. If those are mistakes, they should be corrected to align with your intended system of ODEs.

---

Based on comment discussion:

The issue indeed might be more nuanced. Let's look into a couple of potential solutions:

1. **Solver Choice**: Although `Tsit5()` is generally suitable for non-stiff problems, you might want to try a different solver to see if it makes a difference. You could use `Rodas5()` or `Trapezoid()` to see if they yield different results.
2. **Data Structure**: If `dataValues` is a vector of vectors, flattening it might not be as simple as using `vcat`. Instead, try:

   ```
   dataValuesVector = vcat([d[:]... for d in dataValues]...)
   ```
3. **Loss Function**: Consider defining a custom loss function to handle the specific structure of your data. Here's a simple example:

   ```
   function custom_loss(sol, dataTime, dataValues)
       loss = 0.0
       for (t, d) in zip(dataTime, dataValues)
           loss += sum((sol(t)[:] - d[:]).^2)
       end
       return loss
   end

   cost_function = (params) -> custom_loss(solve(prob, Tsit5(), p=params), dataTime, dataValues)
   ```
4. **Error Message**: If you still encounter issues, look closely at any error messages or warnings. They often contain valuable information that can help pinpoint the exact problem.
5. **Debugging**: Consider adding print statements to monitor the shape of arrays or other variables at critical points in your code. This can help you identify mismatches that might be causing the error.

Experimenting with these aspects should help you identify the issue. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What exactly do you mean with verifying the logic of the ODE system? I tried to make a model that represents finite differences of a 1D model so I thought that every single piece except for the begining and end has a similar ODE.

Comment: Given your explanation , my previous comment on verifying the logic may not apply, as the repetition in the code is intentional to model the finite differences in the system.

The main issue then appears to be the alignment of dimensions in your loss function. By following the suggestion to reshape `dataValues` and ensuring the correct number of parameters in your initial guess, your code should work for this vector ODE system. Make sure to test with those adjustments and see if the optimization proceeds without errors.

Comment: thanks again, unfortunatly the code still isnt working with the changes, but maybe it is the solver choice? Could it be possible there's a solver better suited for that than Tsit5()? The optimizing process is not being initiated and it says "status: failed" on the result. Or did I not fully implement a conversion to a vector with dataValuesVector = vcat([d[:] for d in dataValues]) since this turns dataValues into a vector of vectors?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion earlier. See my edit

Comment: Allright I will try it with these approacgess. Thanks for the help.